# How to use an interface to ensure proper format of component input in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I've got an interface (**option.ts**):

```
export interface Option {
  label: string;
  model: any;
}
```

Which I then import into my component (**form-select.component.ts**):

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';
import {Option} from './option';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-select',
  templateUrl: './app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-select/form-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/assets/scripts/modules/form-controls/form-select/form-select.component.css'],
  inputs: [
    'options',
    'callback',
    'model',
    'label'
  ]
})

export class FormSelectComponent {
  @Input() model: any;
  @Output() modelChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  isOpen: boolean = false;

  toggle() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

  close() {
    this.isOpen = false;
  }

  select(option, callback) {
    this.model = option.model;
    this.modelChange.next(this.model);

    callback ? callback() : false;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to use this interface to ensure that `[options]` that is passed to my select component from another component is correctly formatted and have the right types. `[options]` must be an array looking like this:

```
options = [
  {label: 'Hello world', model: 1},
  {label: 'Hello universe', model: 2},
  {label: 'Hello honey boo boo', model: 3}
]
```

Where each index object will use the `Option` interface, but how do I do this? I remember something along the lines of using `Option[]` in your component class but I'm not sure how to use `[options]` along with the interface and then passing it to the view (or however you're supposed to do it).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do `@Input() options:Option[]`. But it will not have any effect at runtime as there is not runtime check for interfaces on javascript. And because you are using it as `input`, you will only assign values to `options` during runtime. You will benefit from `Option[]` if you are assigning values to `options` manually.

Comment: try converting your values of select/option into interface then pass it into the view by using any dummy method.

Comment: @Abdulrahman So what you're saying is that there is really no point in doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `@Input() options:Option[]`. But it will not have any effect at runtime as there is no runtime check for interfaces in javascript.
Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript) and there are many others.

So, if you are only inputting like this:

```
<form-select [options]="options"></form-select>
```

You cannot ensure that the input `options` is implementing `Option` interface because the value is actually passed during runtime.

But, if you are assigning values to `options` like this:

```
this.options = someOptions;
```

Then, the IDE will show an error saying that `someOptions` is not of type `Option[]`. But this is at compile/development time only.

So, is there no point of typing the variable with an interface ?

I actually think it's good practice. At least, you make your code more readable. But, as far as ensuring the right interface is inputted into `options`, there is no point of using interfaces.