# How to parse JSON string in Typescript

Tags: javascript, json, string, typescript

Is there a way to parse strings as JSON in TypeScript?

For example in JavaScript, we can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Is there a similar function in TypeScript?

I have a JSON object string as follows:

```json
{"name": "Bob", "error": false}
```

Comment: Can't you just use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: On its homepage, it says that "TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript". The JSON.parse() function should be usable like normal.

Comment: I'm using the Atom text editor and when I do a JSON.parse, I get the error: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: This is a very basic question, and it might seem trivial to some but it's a valid question none the less, and an equivalent can't be found in SO (I haven't) so there's no real reason why not to keep the question running, and in my opinion shouldn't be down voted as well.

Comment: @SanketDeshpande When you use `JSON.parse` you get an object as a result and not a `string` (see my answer for more). If you want to turn an object into a string then you need to use `JSON.stringify` instead.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thank you so much for your reply. And I did search the web to check whether JSON.parse() is allowed in Typescript and I did not find any answers. Hence, I posted here.

Comment: Actually it is not a simple question for 2 reasons. Firstly, JSON.parse() doesnt return the same kind of object - it will match some of the interface but anything intelligent, such as accessors, will not be present. Furthermore, surely we want SO to be where people go when they google stuff?

Comment: https://github.com/windhandel/angular-http-deserializer worked for me to get instantiated TypeScript objects from JSON, I tried json2typescript, but it seemed to have trouble with nested Types

Answer (score 374, accepted):

TypeScript is (a superset of) JavaScript, so you just use `JSON.parse` as you would in JavaScript:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Only that in TypeScript you can also have a type for the resulting object:

```
interface MyObj {
    myString: string;
    myNumber: number;
}

let obj: MyObj = JSON.parse('{ "myString": "string", "myNumber": 4 }');
console.log(obj.myString);
console.log(obj.myNumber);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myString%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20myNumber%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20obj%3A%20MyObj%20%3D%20JSON.parse(%27%7B%20%22myString%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%20%22myNumber%22%3A%204%20%7D%27)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(obj.myString)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(obj.myNumber)%3B))

Comment: how to validate that the input is valid (type-checking, one of the purposes of typescript)? replacing the input `'{ "myString": "string", "myNumber": 4 }'` by `'{ "myString": "string", "myNumberBAD": 4 }'` will not fail, and obj.myNumber will return undefined.

Comment: @DavidPortabella You can't have type-checking on the content of a string. It's a runtime issue, and type checking is for compile time

Comment: ok. how can i validate that a typescript obj satisfies its interface at runtime? that is, that myNumber is not undefined in this example. for instance, in Scala Play, you would use `Json.parse(text).validate[MyObj]`. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson
how can you do the same in typescript (maybe there is an external library to do so?)?

Comment: @DavidPortabella There's no way to do that, not easily, because at runtime `MyObj` doesn't exist. There are plenty of other threads in SO about this subject, for example: [Check if an object implements an interface at runtime with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript/40512411#40512411)

Comment: ok, thanks. everyday i am more convinced about using scalajs.

Comment: @DavidPortabella Well, scalajs won't be able to do that without adding a bunch of code to the runtime, so you'll end up with more code than what you wrote. You can write ts/js code to do that as well, and without abstractions, your code will probably be more specific to your needs.

Comment: @DavidPortabella - I haven't used Scalajs but I know Scala provides strong type checking. What is your experience on Scalajs? I also wonder how helpful using scalajs would be considering that frameworks like Angular use typescript. Does any famous JS framework use scalajs?

Comment: JSON.Parse doesn't return a real reference, but rather, an anonymous object which matches most of the propeties. This technique will fail with this object - there will be no b on the constructed object: class Something {public a:string; public get b() { return a;} }

Comment: @gburton In this example, there's no class, so your point is irrelevant. It is indeed a real reference, but not to an instance of a class. The OP asked about how to parse a json encoded string into a js object with a defined type, my answer references that.

Comment: @NitzanTomer Maybe I was too hasty - what if we expanded your answer? I was just annoyed becuase I wasted 20 minutes on the mystery of the missing accessor before realising that

Comment: @gburton That's a completely different question though, and therefore requires a different answer, see this answer of mine for a scenario like I believe you're describing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43314819/942852

Comment: @gburton BTW, I replied in the same thread to another question, exactly what you wrote me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314791/how-to-instantiate-an-object-in-typescript-by-specifying-each-property-and-its-v/45340173#comment91225167_45340173) but there the question did include the class instance, unlike here.

Comment: You're probably right, but the only way somebody new to typescript would know that is by finding it by accident, maybe you could put a disclaimer and a link to your other answer? an instance of a class is a typescript object, and the question title doesn't specify "native javascript object".

Comment: How to handle invalid json?

Comment: @NitzanTomer to me it gives this error `Cannot access 'JSON.parse' because 'JSON' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'parse' in 'JSON' with 'JSON["parse"]'?`. Not sure what I am missing. Is there any module which we need to import? I have already installed `axios`. Any suggestion/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 116):

## Type-safe `JSON.parse`

You can continue to use `JSON.parse`, as TypeScript is a [superset](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#a-typed-superset-of-javascript) of JavaScript:

> This means you can take any working JavaScript code and put it in a TypeScript file without worrying about exactly how it is written.

There is a problem left: [`JSON.parse`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/35c1ba6/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1059) returns [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), which undermines type safety ([don't use `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any)).

Here are three solutions for stronger types, ordered by ascending complexity:

### 1. User-defined type guards

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWeA5gNza4AmEFAxnWMLQHs85KnUYssAX2zYAZgFc8XfkKi0KcRJAAUA8gTwgAlOQFqKsBEnSso1CMHnU8UAESESrtS7MAyX24c3LwqeF70UALY0ljYXEJUUABWFKqoAORobh4QruSuAGICAq4ANIGcPLR8gmH5AEIE1F6S6RLxeIlgTRQQbFCoAFIAygDyAHIAdN3UvdopQkbYtLJQ2uqaSNozvWxGRjY4UAD0x1BsZqkkwAAW9AxQAO60t1Dx1PbKADYgUKCQ-QEACMkhBlLYOqkvhBJl8BAxtj0+pMglUaosJJIoBAvr1DrhTtiPgJqFAbgY2F97kxvAA3AhU-ojCZQWQkogEYAQhICaGw+HaVwASTw9MZfyQriMmKAA)

```
// For example, you expect to parse a given value with `MyType` shape
type MyType = { name: string; description: string; }

// Validate this value with a custom type guard (extend to your needs)
function isMyType(o: any): o is MyType {
  return "name" in o && "description" in o
}

const json = '{ "name": "Foo", "description": "Bar" }';
const parsed = JSON.parse(json);
if (isMyType(parsed)) {
  // do something with now correctly typed object
  parsed.description
} else { 
// error handling; invalid JSON format 
}
```

`isMyType` is called a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Its advantage is, that you get a fully typed object inside truthy `if` branch.

### 2. Generic `JSON.parse` wrapper

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUB2AhgLYQBcUAzsAE4CWeA5gNza4AmEFAxnWMLQHs85KnUYssAX2zZQkKAAUC1ChABKnAK4AbYAB54APijJWUAD7ooYZarbl4TKAAsCFAKLVqA6uQBmBNqqThBePgD85Jp4HH70EGxQ0jgWVjYqCZFQ0bHxbE6uHmG+UDSaECHFWdEA1ngCAO54STJYXEJUlAR+EABSFEJKGSZQBoYAFHIQDJrK9lDjAuQEeCAAlCbGAlC0FFDwG8jGkxAAHsAiNPQMa+RDqhoUOvpGm+hmNCDvKbjteJ3pOwjXoAZQA8gA5AB0gIgJ3OazMuGoEGAmmozSmMzm41hbA24TStgSABoXG5PN4SgEgtBJFByGhyUUqeQynSzPSuARgFxnAtQlSNpgflAUWiMVZCpSfGzqOUyYKfC0Uslktg-NEuPwhDsKHBEJBFstVrcoNtdrAEEhvsjUejmgAiQgkR07ZrbABknqgjo43F4Orwbvo5uw6raHWAUAAVgNmqgAORM53ECCO8iOgBiAgEjrJfs4PFofEEwczACFlG7JImJH9OiinroRhRun14-c4bsDUg1uM40INgB6YdirS6O7Ex7PPS9yCGbC0PwLJvPKHS4rCswNgTaCBQ7QCBjjR1K6gM4eOjZQUdQM7AUKEbRQNg8gj4ATRgBugVobChKAABFtgGEh72KckYm0a4XFCA9w3vWlbSgXd90PY9xjXXQYWJAD-WLUsh1vMc8XIecIHDbAgA)

Create a generic wrapper around `JSON.parse`, which takes one type guard as input and returns the parsed, typed value or error result:

```
const safeJsonParse = <T>(guard: (o: any) => o is T) => 
  (text: string): ParseResult<T> => {
    const parsed = JSON.parse(text)
    return guard(parsed) ? { parsed, hasError: false } : { hasError: true }
  }

type ParseResult<T> =
  | { parsed: T; hasError: false; error?: undefined }
  | { parsed?: undefined; hasError: true; error?: unknown }
```

Usage example:

```
const json = '{ "name": "Foo", "description": "Bar" }';
const result = safeJsonParse(isMyType)(json) // result: ParseResult<MyType>
if (result.hasError) {
  console.log("error :/")  // further error handling here
} else {
  console.log(result.parsed.description) // result.parsed now has type `MyType`
}
```

`safeJsonParse` might be extended to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) or try/catch `JSON.parse` errors.

### 3. External libraries

Writing type guard functions manually becomes cumbersome, if you need to validate many different values. There are libraries to assist with this task - examples (no comprehensive list):

- [`io-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts): has [`fp-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) peer dependency, uses functional programming style
- [`zod`](https://github.com/vriad/zod): strives to be more [procedural / object-oriented](https://vriad.com/blog/zod) than `io-ts`
- [`typescript-is`](https://github.com/woutervh-/typescript-is): TS transformer for compiler API, additional wrapper like [ttypescript](https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript) needed
- [`typescript-json-schema`](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema)/[`ajv`](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv): Create JSON schema from types and validate it with `ajv`

---

**More infos**

- [Runtime type checking #1573](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1573)
- [Interface type check with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript)
- [TypeScript: validating external data](https://2ality.com/2020/06/validating-data-typescript.html)

Comment: Please update your answer here with the code from the TS Playground for number 2.

Answer (score 11):

If you want your JSON to have a validated Typescript type, you will need to do that validation work yourself. This is nothing new. In plain Javascript, you would need to do the same.

## Validation

I like to express my validation logic as a set of "transforms". I define a `Descriptor` as a map of transforms:

```js
type Descriptor<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: (v: any) => T[P];
};
```

Then I can make a function that will apply these transforms to arbitrary input:

```js
function pick<T>(v: any, d: Descriptor<T>): T {
  const ret: any = {};
  for (let key in d) {
    try {
      const val = d[key](v[key]);
      if (typeof val !== "undefined") {
        ret[key] = val;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      const msg = err instanceof Error ? err.message : String(err);
      throw new Error(`could not pick ${key}: ${msg}`);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Now, not only am I validating my JSON input, but I am building up a Typescript type as I go. The above generic types ensure that the result infers the types from your "transforms".

In case the transform throws an error (which is how you would implement validation), I like to wrap it with another error showing which key caused the error.

## Usage

In your example, I would use this as follows:

```js
const value = pick(JSON.parse('{"name": "Bob", "error": false}'), {
  name: String,
  error: Boolean,
});
```

Now `value` will be typed, since `String` and `Boolean` are both "transformers" in the sense they take input and return a typed output.

Furthermore, the `value` will *actually be* that type. In other words, if `name` were actually `123`, it will be transformed to `"123"` so that you have a valid string. This is because we used `String` at runtime, a built-in function that accepts arbitrary input and returns a `string`.

You can see this working [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSzMA9sgPAFQD4oBeKAbwCgpqoBtABSlQDsoBrCETAMyjwF0AXFAAUAN2EBDZiACUJIngb8A3BQC+aitwCuzRMFSZWYVIjb4C4qTIA0UACbC4SNBmyXZwvOSo1ExvDAUMgQwDYgJOSaftTc2KIANmHsnEysDvKUNDlQwMiR2bnFAcxBUGKSiVEOtBwg-OJ1nPyyasXFqLwioJA8FVVQAITEpABEeg4Q3CwQDmNZsR3FocDNDVGVie3LNOpLOepQiJLAiAAWohDIyIu7-oHBALbwAOZR18jpQdKIEP0AURuCQA-FBPgA6J4IeCSV7QYQAZXyLFeIk+bQOHWA52QmAA7lBmBBCUC8cgRAADAI6RIOImYYKmcxQAAkZHq6mE7Jer3UlMxy32hyWqx0yFYqzU+wopXKWx00FIzLYIgAUoiAPIAOQhYEkyHgEBEAHIyGNmJJoWNhGMAEKYABGY3sY0+2BtUG4VSN6hNsnsRWoluhSJRzFetiW7uQwgdmGS0ij6kxssCCYgEMSmDRCogmKAA). Try the following things to convince yourself:

- Hover over the `const value` definition to see that the pop-over shows the correct type.
- Try changing `"Bob"` to `123` and re-run the sample. In your console, you will see that the name has been properly converted to the string `"123"`.

Comment: you gave an example, "if `name` were actually `123`, it will be transformed to `"123"`. This seems to be incorrect. My `value` is coming back `{name: 123..` not `{name:"123"..` when I copy paste all your code exactly and make that change.

Comment: Weird, it works for me. Try it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html (using `123` instead of `"Bob"`).

Comment: I dont think you need to define a `Transformed` type. You can just use `Object`.
`type Descriptor<T extends Object> = { ... };`

Comment: Thanks @lovasoa, you are correct. The `Transformed` type is totally unnecessary. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: If you actually want to validate that the JSON Object has the correct types, you would *not* want `123` to be automatically converted to a string `"123"`, since it is a number in the JSON object.

Comment: Correct. If you want to validate the JSON object, your transformer should check, e.g. instead of `String` use `(v: any) => { if (typeof v === 'string') return v; else throw new TypeError("wrong type"); }`

Answer (score 9):

There is a great library for it [ts-json-object](https://github.com/moshegottlieb/ts-json-object)

In your case you would need to run the following code:

```
import {JSONObject, required} from 'ts-json-object'

class Response extends JSONObject {
    @required
    name: string;

    @required
    error: boolean;
}

let resp = new Response({"name": "Bob", "error": false});
```

This library will validate the json before parsing

Answer (score 5):

Use [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) to safely parse JSON in TypeScript. More on this shortly.
`JSON.parse()` returns type `any` and is sufficient in the "happy path" but can lead to errors related to type-safety downstream which defeats the purpose of TypeScript. For example:

```
interface User {
  name: string,
  balance: number
}

const json = '{"name": "Bob", "balance": "100"}' //note the string "100"
const user:User = JSON.parse(json)

const newBalance = user.balance + user.balance * 0.05 //should be 105 after interest
console.log(newBalance ) //but it ends up as 1005 which is clearly wrong
```

So let quicktype do the heavy lifting and generate the code. Copy and paste the string below in quicktype.

```
{
  "name": "Bob",
  "balance": 100
}
```

Make sure to choose `TypeScript` as the language and enable "Verify JSON.parse results at runtime"

Now we can defensively handle exception (if any) at the time of parsing and prevent errors from happening downstream.

```
import { Convert, User } from "./user";

const json =
  '{"firstName": "Kevin", "lastName": "Le", "accountBalance": "100"}';

try {
  const user = Convert.toUser(json);
  console.log(user);
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Handle error", e);
}
```

`user.ts` is the file generated by quicktype.

```
// To parse this data:
//
//   import { Convert, User } from "./file";
//
//   const user = Convert.toUser(json);
//
// These functions will throw an error if the JSON doesn't
// match the expected interface, even if the JSON is valid.

export interface User {
    name:    string;
    balance: number;
}

// Converts JSON strings to/from your types
// and asserts the results of JSON.parse at runtime
export class Convert {
    public static toUser(json: string): User {
        return cast(JSON.parse(json), r("User"));
    }

    public static userToJson(value: User): string {
        return JSON.stringify(uncast(value, r("User")), null, 2);
    }
}

function invalidValue(typ: any, val: any, key: any = ''): never {
    if (key) {
        throw Error(`Invalid value for key "${key}". Expected type ${JSON.stringify(typ)} but got ${JSON.stringify(val)}`);
    }
    throw Error(`Invalid value ${JSON.stringify(val)} for type ${JSON.stringify(typ)}`, );
}

function jsonToJSProps(typ: any): any {
    if (typ.jsonToJS === undefined) {
        const map: any = {};
        typ.props.forEach((p: any) => map[p.json] = { key: p.js, typ: p.typ });
        typ.jsonToJS = map;
    }
    return typ.jsonToJS;
}

function jsToJSONProps(typ: any): any {
    if (typ.jsToJSON === undefined) {
        const map: any = {};
        typ.props.forEach((p: any) => map[p.js] = { key: p.json, typ: p.typ });
        typ.jsToJSON = map;
    }
    return typ.jsToJSON;
}

function transform(val: any, typ: any, getProps: any, key: any = ''): any {
    function transformPrimitive(typ: string, val: any): any {
        if (typeof typ === typeof val) return val;
        return invalidValue(typ, val, key);
    }

    function transformUnion(typs: any[], val: any): any {
        // val must validate against one typ in typs
        const l = typs.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            const typ = typs[i];
            try {
                return transform(val, typ, getProps);
            } catch (_) {}
        }
        return invalidValue(typs, val);
    }

    function transformEnum(cases: string[], val: any): any {
        if (cases.indexOf(val) !== -1) return val;
        return invalidValue(cases, val);
    }

    function transformArray(typ: any, val: any): any {
        // val must be an array with no invalid elements
        if (!Array.isArray(val)) return invalidValue("array", val);
        return val.map(el => transform(el, typ, getProps));
    }

    function transformDate(val: any): any {
        if (val === null) {
            return null;
        }
        const d = new Date(val);
        if (isNaN(d.valueOf())) {
            return invalidValue("Date", val);
        }
        return d;
    }

    function transformObject(props: { [k: string]: any }, additional: any, val: any): any {
        if (val === null || typeof val !== "object" || Array.isArray(val)) {
            return invalidValue("object", val);
        }
        const result: any = {};
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(props).forEach(key => {
            const prop = props[key];
            const v = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(val, key) ? val[key] : undefined;
            result[prop.key] = transform(v, prop.typ, getProps, prop.key);
        });
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(val).forEach(key => {
            if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(props, key)) {
                result[key] = transform(val[key], additional, getProps, key);
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    if (typ === "any") return val;
    if (typ === null) {
        if (val === null) return val;
        return invalidValue(typ, val);
    }
    if (typ === false) return invalidValue(typ, val);
    while (typeof typ === "object" && typ.ref !== undefined) {
        typ = typeMap[typ.ref];
    }
    if (Array.isArray(typ)) return transformEnum(typ, val);
    if (typeof typ === "object") {
        return typ.hasOwnProperty("unionMembers") ? transformUnion(typ.unionMembers, val)
            : typ.hasOwnProperty("arrayItems")    ? transformArray(typ.arrayItems, val)
            : typ.hasOwnProperty("props")         ? transformObject(getProps(typ), typ.additional, val)
            : invalidValue(typ, val);
    }
    // Numbers can be parsed by Date but shouldn't be.
    if (typ === Date && typeof val !== "number") return transformDate(val);
    return transformPrimitive(typ, val);
}

function cast<T>(val: any, typ: any): T {
    return transform(val, typ, jsonToJSProps);
}

function uncast<T>(val: T, typ: any): any {
    return transform(val, typ, jsToJSONProps);
}

function a(typ: any) {
    return { arrayItems: typ };
}

function u(...typs: any[]) {
    return { unionMembers: typs };
}

function o(props: any[], additional: any) {
    return { props, additional };
}

function m(additional: any) {
    return { props: [], additional };
}

function r(name: string) {
    return { ref: name };
}

const typeMap: any = {
    "User": o([
        { json: "name", js: "name", typ: "" },
        { json: "balance", js: "balance", typ: 0 },
    ], false),
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can additionally use libraries that perform type validation of your json, such as [Sparkson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sparkson). They allow you to define a TypeScript class, to which you'd like to parse your response, in your case it could be:

```
import { Field } from "sparkson";
class Response {
   constructor(
      @Field("name") public name: string,
      @Field("error") public error: boolean
   ) {}
}
```

The library will validate if the required fields are present in the JSON payload and if their types are correct. It can also do a bunch of validations and conversions.

Comment: You should mention, that you are the main contributor of above library.

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.parse` is available in TypeScript, so you can just use it :

```
JSON.parse('{"name": "Bob", "error": false}') // Returns a value of type 'any'
```

However, you will often want to parse a JSON object while making sure it matches a certain type, rather than dealing with a value of type `any`. In that case, you can define a function such as the following :

```
function parse_json<TargetType extends Object>(
  json: string,
  type_definitions: { [Key in keyof TargetType]: (raw_value: any) => TargetType[Key] }
): TargetType {
  const raw = JSON.parse(json); 
  const result: any = {};
  for (const key in type_definitions) result[key] = type_definitions[key](raw[key]);
  return result;
}
```

This function takes a JSON string and an object containing individual functions that load each field of the object you are creating. You can use it like so:

```
const value = parse_json(
  '{"name": "Bob", "error": false}',
  { name: String, error: Boolean, }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

### TS has a JavaScript runtime

Typescript has a JavaScript runtime because it gets compiled to JS. This means JS objects which are built in as part of the language such as `JSON`, `Object`, and `Math` are also available in TS. Therefore we can just use the `JSON.parse` method to parse the JSON string.

### Example:

```
const JSONStr = '{"name": "Bob", "error": false}'

// The JSON object is part of the runtime
const parsedObj = JSON.parse(JSONStr);

console.log(parsedObj);
// [LOG]: {
//   "name": "Bob",
//   "error": false
// } 

// The Object object is also part of the runtime so we can use it in TS
const objKeys = Object.keys(parsedObj);

console.log(objKeys);
// [LOG]: ["name", "error"]
```

The only thing now is that parsedObj is type `any` which is generally a bad practice in TS. We can type the object if we are using type guards. Here is an example:

```
const JSONStr = '{"name": "Bob", "error": false}'
const parsedObj = JSON.parse(JSONStr);

interface nameErr {
  name: string;
  error: boolean;
}

function isNameErr(arg: any): arg is nameErr {
  if (typeof arg.name === 'string' && typeof arg.error === 'boolean') {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

if (isNameErr(parsedObj)) {
  // Within this if statement parsedObj is type nameErr;
  parsedObj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you do **typeof** of your json object it turns out to be string which is of typescript. You can read more on that here: [Typescript: difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727044/typescript-difference-between-string-and-string)

So just try this way and it will work-

```
JSON.parse(String({"name": "Bob", "error": false}))
```

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion, for data contained in an associative array | Map<string,any>,  a bit relaxed (only keys checking) but the easiest way on my opinion  (**JsDoc version**)

(uses an emtpy class instance for type reference and per key matching, returns 'undefined' if parsing or key matching fail )

## types.js

```
export class FormCheckError {
    constructor(
        /** @type {string?}*/ message, 
        /** @type {string?}*/ oldValue
    ) { 
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.errorMessage = message;
    }
}
```

## json.js

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param   { Object<keyof T,any>[] } keys2Check 
 * @param   { string } jsonString
 * @returns { T | undefined }
 */
 export function JsonCheckedParse(keys2Check = [],jsonString = '{}') {
    try {
        let result = JSON.parse(jsonString)
        let resultKeys = Object.keys(result)
        if (keys2Check.length !== resultKeys.length) {
            return undefined;
        } 
        keys2Check.forEach(function(key) {
            if (resultKeys.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                return undefined;                
            }
        })
        return result;
    } catch(e) {
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

Usage scenario :

1.Encoding :

## ssr-side.js

```
import { FormCheckError } from 'types'

...
if (oldValue.length == 0) {
    return {
      body:  JSON.stringify(
        new FormCheckError(
            "You shouldn't post empty entries.", 
            oldValue
        )
     )
    }
}
...
```

2.Decoding:

## browser-side.js

```
import { FormCheckError } from 'types'  
import { JsonCheckedParse } from 'json'     
...

/** @type {import('./$types').ActionData} */  // Sveltekit stuff
export let form;  // response received from 'ssr-side.js'

// will be undefined in case of type mismatch beetween encoded & decoded
/** @type {FormCheckError | undefined}*/
let checkError = JsonCheckedParse(
    Object.keys(new FormCheckError()), // an empty class instance for knowing its keys
    form?.body || '{}' // the JSON to parse and check for type
) 

...
if (checkError?.errorMessage) {
    console.log(String(checkError.errorMessage))
}
...
```

Answer (score -11):

Yes it's a little tricky in **TypeScript** but you can do the below example like this

```html
let decodeData  =  JSON.parse(`${jsonResponse}`);
```

Comment: Does not answer the question properly, bad code/example (no point in `${jsonResponse}`)