# Ionic : How to view JSON data using TypeScript

Tags: json, typescript

I want to be able to view JSON data through HTML using TypeScript.

My folders are as such:

- test/test.html
- test/test.ts
- test/test.json

```json
{
  "animals": [ {
    "cat": "meow",
    "dog": "woof",
    "bird": "chirp"
  } ]  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON string in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688822/how-to-parse-json-string-in-typescript)

Comment: What do you mean by "view JSON data through HTML"? Do you mean translate JSON into HTML? Because there's a lot to that, depending on how you want to see the data.

Comment: please tell us how you want to display the data

Comment: I would like to see it displayed out. 
<p>Cat:{{cat.value}</p>

Comment: @RodFlores Are you using Angular or some other template engine?

Comment: yes, i am using angular 2, from ionic 2