# How to extract information from angular output

Tags: json, angular

If I log the full data from an `Angular` client I get

> object { type: "message", target: {_}, errorCode: undefiend,
>   errorMessage: undefined, data: "{\"data\":[\"124",\"611\"]}",
>   lastEventId: ""}

I want to grab the `{\"data\":[\"124",\"611\"]}` part to send it as json to a client. Using `JSON.parse(data.data)` though gives me

> data: "{\"data\":[\"124",\"611\"]}", lastEventId: ""}

Is it possible to just grab the `"{\"data\":[\"124",\"611\"]}"` since otherwise the client has problems with the deserialization.

Comment: It's a type string, so parse it to JSON object then `.data`

Comment: Should I do this mydata => Json.parse(data) and can then get the string I want by mydata.data. Is that what you mean? Sorry, this is absolutely not my terrain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have your initial string in `myobject_string`.
Then, you extract the JSON to a Javascript object with: `const myobject = JSON.parse(myobject_string)`.

Then, the data you are looking for is in `myobject.data`.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688822/how-to-parse-json-string-in-typescript) for more example code on `JSON.parse`.