# How to use R.pick with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I was trying out something like

```js
import R from 'ramda'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import {promisify} from 'util'

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile)

export async function discoverPackageInfo(): Promise<{
  name: string,
  version: string
  description: string
}> {
  return readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json'))
    .then(b => b.toString())
    .then(JSON.parse)
    .then(R.pick([
      'name',
      'description',
      'version',
    ]))
}
```

But I got

```
src/file.ts:13:3 - error TS2322: Type '{ name: string; version: string; description: string; } | Pick<any, never>' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; version: string; description: string; }'.
  Type 'Pick<any, never>' is missing the following properties from type '{ name: string; version: string; description: string; }': name, version, description

 13   return readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'package.json'))
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 14     .then(b => b.toString())
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
... 
 19       'version',
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 20     ]))
    ~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I know that using `async` and `.then` is not too kosher.

Comment: `async` is actually unnecessary here. The code works without it

Comment: Correct. However, I'm structuring my code to have async on anything that's not CPU-only in order to force to think about things right. Ends up being an exercise in structure and annotation, and I've been finding it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON.parse` [returns `any`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/16031bc/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1059). The return type after [`R.pick`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1db9bfa/types/ramda/index.d.ts#L1435) resolves like this:

```
.then(R.pick([ 'name', 'description', 'version' ])) 
=>
type Return = Pick<any, Inner> // resolves to {}; any stems from JSON.parse
type Inner = Exclude<keyof any,
    Exclude<keyof any, "name" | "description" | "version">> // never
```

You want `{ name: string, version: string description: string }`, but get `{}`. To fix that, [assert the desired type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) explicitly for `JSON.parse` (I named it `MyThing`):

```
readFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "package.json"))
  .then(b => b.toString())
  .then(s => JSON.parse(s) as MyThing)
  .then(R.pick(["name", "description", "version"]));
```

[Parsing can be made more type-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438143/5669456), e.g. by using [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) / type guards:

```
export async function discoverPackageInfo(): Promise<MyThing> {
  return readFile(...).then(...)
    .then(safeParse(assertMyThing)) // <-- change
    .then(R.pick(...));
}

const safeParse = <T>(assertFn: (o: any) => asserts o is T) => (s: string) => {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(s);
  assertFn(parsed);
  return parsed;
}

function assertMyThing(o: any): asserts o is MyThing {
  if (!("name" in o) || !("version" in o) || !("description" in o))
    throw Error();
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJTgMyhEcBEUCGIAmOmAsAFCiSwoDOKaGmy1J5408YOMAFnelpx4sK7OAG84YesGrBkATzgBfPgwCuMYABsWZAMYQAdtXhQApjnwAxbWbgBeSdNkKAFEwB05yza1mAlGRkAPTBIcFwAPIAMgAiADRwAOoAkgAqABJwAKIICJEI4UGkYmRwcDjU8oZ6KGo1mkZw+DIGAG5mUAAKOHoA1jgA5mYphsgQkVr4rv4AXHBdzmYAPKWk5eWGeGbzJlDAhoNlGx1Qska7MPuHx+X4ZtR6+2CNhpfXR+vKAHzit3DmGBqKCGAEWay2VyCbgeABWEAOrgA+kiWiDtolMB4PJhMZx+kMzHDqEZMP5Al8NnAPDwzIZXAAjBy-Bk0iAAZSuB0GMwpVPKNO4dNcACl2ZEAHIeThnAL-AW0+kIaXAfquADamC2IDMuKw90ez1eeswp3OhkwAF1ycclMVyjB5GA7AgzECQQ4Fqq+sscIZ5IlRoZOr9QuI7V9Hc64EHOp7sgAPPRaNT3Zb-PpmeQQZAVf3xf6J5OplaZ7O5v0BrDa3VwAA++oeT2AL2ApPrWDNbYt32OoYiwdOZAjRVIYYl2SSiQAwpEALJdFLRbLs0dkNYOp12OfyNLcbmejcbGvvbn-LsXOB7M+U5pNo3d083L4jr6Vaq1ZD1PSvZqtCCnD0BLDKM4wSmYADuMzzIs6AyCsO57tyvxHuUgLAqCrjymCPiQtCcIIvSKJojWmLYia+IDMMxKkjat5UoKwpMvYLJspyHy8thCpCvStAsXAYqStKOCyq41D+BUtCIfuhwSWGFhVBUWgwJ0WyaB0cCuAAjHy-LlGGjG8TgyBmD0omVNQnQwNJ3LknAYYJtAV7GXYODKapXDABprgAEy6XphmuMqYDehqWrbCaBrNq2pKYheFrWv5cC6a+5QGMY8DUC5ZmWZ6yxpN8rgWVZVhvJpEDzJWEn8cVsC0BAcAyHAaTVb8WG3tQT6fOUrV-Le6UmJIImWfgnqCVKMqWWJSW1TApVQsNZj4El6EepNS22vadQNN2kmWbANmHK4FV5vIcx7VZ9WNVJu4yYMfVUnImkAISuOFOqYI1oIQBJdYNq9pqdOan0HHAP31v9b1RQ+7agz9SUOtwaAQTkUBoFAMybaQxwDfA8COMFoWajWkX3i2xpxUD3ZWv4rioXAJ5YNEajALi-zQ+Tj5YOMEBs7e8XzAAzLaFIRkAA) <sup>(external type imports in the playground might take a bit to load, otherwise paste in your own environment)</sup>

Comment: Great help, thank you! Is there a more standard/packaged way of doing this? Like, generating an assert function from a type definition? I haven't gone through the handbook (I'm just learning through exercise) and I'd appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I am not sure of a generator for assertion functions. But there are a lot of auto generating type guard libraries out there, personally I find [io-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/io-ts) and [typescript-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-is) appealing! And seems to be actively maintained and supported. You also can have a look at [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480160/typescript-check-object-by-type-or-interface-at-runtime-with-typeguards-in-2020/59483318) for a starting point.

Comment: Btw: if you then wanted to use assertion functions based on generated type guards, conversion should be no problem, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAzsAJwEsA7AcygF8BYAKDoHoG84BbaUSKMgVwwIAmdAGY8SAY2BE4JKEVzw4ACmE4MJEAEocwublgI0dKCagEIwHgVkAiDDbmzhdGvVpMoPXBwAW8qKISUjJQwIjiMgBuEATAoeDQvPwCUAC0AHyYuN6x0k5iknkiBcGySYIAKnAAgtkxwAA8FekqJDhKcGoamsiZiP4VADRQnZjdanWx+v36FUa0pnK6SgCEwiQdmj3APgRwAO5QJBCHAKIEewRKmi50dAIQ4gA2-NARJPgjXSB05QJVtRywCU8kUwzgN1ocCAA).