# How to convert a string to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

In my application I am getting a response like below:

```
{"success":true,"data":"{\"status\": \"Failed\", \"percentage_completed\": \"0\", \"actions\": \"Error: Insufficient argument: 1\\n\"}","message":"Logs fetched successfully."}
```

How can I convert this into JSON? I tried *JSON.parse*, but it doesn’t seem to work. Is there another way to convert this string into a *valid* JSON format?

Comment: That string is already in [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Do you mean you want to parse it into a JavaScript object?

Comment: What about `JSON.parse()` didn't work? Did you get an error message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON string in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688822/how-to-parse-json-string-in-typescript)

Comment: Looks like this is ajax call response. You want to use `JSON.parse(response.data)`.

Answer (score 24):

I understand where the confusion is coming from. The provided object has a property which contains a JSON string. In this case, the "data" attribute contains the JSON string which you need to parse. Look at the following example.

```js
var result = {"success":true,"data":"{\"status\": \"Failed\", \"percentage_completed\": \"0\", \"actions\": \"Error: Insufficient argument: 1\\n\"}","message":"Logs fetched successfully."};

JSON.parse(result); // should fail
JSON.parse(result["data"]); // should work
JSON.parse(result.data) // or if you prefer this notation
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
let data = {"success":true,"data":"{\"status\": \"Failed\", \"percentage_completed\": \"0\", \"actions\": \"Error: Insufficient argument: 1\\n\"}","message":"Logs fetched successfully."}
data.data = JSON.parse(data.data);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Re *"Try this"*: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what kind of JSON input is it? Invalid? Valid? The same? Different? What is the idea/gist? What did you change and why?  From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75515547/edit), not here in comments (*** ***without*** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).