# Angular doesn't create an object out of JSON response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, django-celery, flower

I'm trying to create an object out of my json (from a http request) but it's a plain string.

**Interfaces:**

```
export interface CeleryTask {
  uuid: string,
  state: string,
  received: string,
  result: Chat,
}

export interface Chat {
  id: number;
  chatTitle: string;
  chatId: string;
  users: User[];
  archived: boolean,
}
```

GET Request in my service:

```
loadAllSuccessTasksFromFlower(): Observable<CeleryTask[]> {
    return this.http.get<CeleryTask[]>("http://localhost:5566/api/tasks?state=SUCCESS")
      .pipe(map(response => Object.entries(response)
        .map(entry => ({
          uuid: entry[0],
          state: entry[1].state,
          received: entry[1].received,
          result: entry[1].result
        }))))
  }
```

**HTTP Response:**

```
{
   "67fe1783-4451-4fa5-838e-b78279fd5c07":{
      "uuid":"67fe1783-4451-4fa5-838e-b78279fd5c07",
      "name":"upload.tasks.importWorkTask",
      "state":"SUCCESS",
      "received":1668285215.4455156,
      "sent":null,
      "started":1668285219.4739492,
      "rejected":null,
      "succeeded":1668285419.1474545,
      "failed":null,
      "retried":null,
      "revoked":null,
      "args":"('C:\\Users\\xx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\xxx', 'xx.pdf')",
      "kwargs":"{}",
      "eta":null,
      "expires":null,
      "retries":0,
      "result":"{'id': 9, 'chatTitle': 'My Chat'}",
      "exception":null,
      "timestamp":1668285419.1474545,
      "runtime":199.67199999999866,
      "traceback":null,
      "exchange":null,
      "routing_key":null,
      "clock":599,
      "client":null,
      "root":"67fe1783-4451-4fa5-838e-b78279fd5c07",
      "root_id":"67fe1783-4451-4fa5-838e-b78279fd5c07",
      "parent":null,
      "parent_id":null,
      "children":[
         
      ],
      "worker":"celery@xxx"
   }
```

When I console.log the result:

```
{
  "uuid": "67fe1783-4451-4fa5-838e-b78279fd5c07",
  "state": "SUCCESS",
  "received": 1668285215.4455156,
  "result": "{'id': 9, 'chatTitle': 'My Chat'}"
}
```

The id & chatTitle is not a chat object, it's an plain string. So it's not possible to access **object.result.chatTitle**

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the object from the received string would be

```
result: JSON.parse(entry[1].result);
```

Build a type guard to let typescript understand that you really have a Chat object

```
function isChat(o: any): o is Chat {
  // check whatever is necessary to be a Chat object
  return "id" in o && "chatTitle" in o
}
```

Use the typeguard like this

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(jsonString);
if (isChat(parsed)) {
  // do something with now correctly typed object
} else { 
  // error handling; invalid JSON format 
}
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438143/7869582 for more info on that

Comment: I've tried that already =>  TS2345: Argument of type 'Chat' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Typescript does complain as it is not sure that your string is really that object. You can use "type guards" for that. Have look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/62438143/7869582

Comment: Thank you so far @andymel. Could you give me an example? I'm struggeling with that

Comment: edited the answer...see the link for more info

Comment: Thanks! Can I implement that in my map function?

Comment: Write a mapper function like 'toCeleryTask(responseEntry: any): CeleryTask' and  use it with .map(toCeleryTask)

Comment: ERROR SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data | when I try to do this: const parsed = JSON.parse(responseEntry[1].result);
JSON is: {'id': 9, 'chatTitle': 'My Chat'}

Comment: Problem solved: It was because of the single quote of json..