# Checking the structure of an object returned by a http service against a typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to check that the content/structure of the http JSON response does indeed match a typescript interface/type. This is in the context of javascript integration tests against a running backend.

For instance one of our typescript interfaces is as follows:

```
export interface CurrentUser {
  id: number;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  roles: string[];
}
```

If the backend returns an object that contains an `age` property and no `firstname` property, then I would like somehow to be notified at runtime that the structure of the returned object differs and the test would fail.

Also, I want to avoid having to manually code a check/assertion for each of the fields.

I understand typescript interfaces no longer exist at runtime. Then how can I rely on typescript for such checks?

If that is not possible with typescript, then what would be an alternative (library, pattern)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an object implements an interface at runtime with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no *native* way to use a typescript interface directly to perform runtime type assertions. You should create your own javascript implementation instead.

*(i) There is an [unofficial TS compiler](https://github.com/pcan/reflec-ts) that allows for automating this process.*

> Also, I want to avoid having to manually code a check/assertion for each of the fields.

Unfortunately, unless you decide to go with a solution such as a custom compiler you'll have to. For example, you could test objects like this:

```js
const isValidUser = (object) => {
    if ('object' !== typeof object) return false;

    const { id, firstname, lastname, roles } = object;
    
    return typeof id === 'number'
        && typeof firstname === 'string'
        && typeof lastname === 'string'
        && Array.isArray(roles)
        && roles.reduce((acc, value) => acc && typeof value === 'string', true);
}

// prints false (missing lastname property)
document.body.innerText = isValidUser({
    id: 1,
    firstname: 'John',
    roles: ['admin', 'content-editor'],
});
```

The example above performs all basic checks for all properties (presence and type). Additionally, you could use libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) and [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/) to clean up the type checking syntax, and make things a little easier to understand (and maintain). An example:

```js
const { all, allPass, pipe, prop } = R;
const { isArray, isNumber, isObject, isString } = _;

const isValidUser = allPass([
    isObject,
    pipe(prop('id'), isNumber),
    pipe(prop('firstname'), isString),
    pipe(prop('lastname'), isString),
    pipe(prop('roles'), isArray),
    pipe(prop('roles'), all(isString)),
]);

// prints false (missing lastname property)
document.body.innerText = isValidUser({
    id: 1,
    firstname: 'John',
    roles: ['admin', 'content-editor'],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```