# Strict data type for json file

Tags: angularjs, json, typescript

When I get the data from the json I first create a class and define all the variables I get in json for strict data type like my json file is

```
 {"fname":"Mark","lname":"jhony"}
```

so in angular i make the class like this

```
export class user{

 fname: string;
 lname : string;
}
```

I am confuse how to make the class for the following json data

```
{"fname":"Mark","lname":"jhony",
 "parcels":[
   {
    "parcelId":123,
    "parcelName :"asd",
    "parcelItems:[
       { 
        "itemId":2,
        "itemName":"perfume"
       },
       { 
         "itemId":4,
         "itemName":"soap"
       }
     ]
]}
```

I tried to add array in the class but not getting what would be the best way to handle it in angularjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would use an interface to represent a data structure of primitive values, for example:

```
interface ParcelItem {
  itemId: number;
  itemName: string;
}
interface Parcel {
  parcelId: number;
  parcelName: string;
  parcelItems: ParcelItem[];
}
interface User {
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  Parcels: Parcel[];
}
```

Depending upon how you acquire the JSON and parse it you can specify the interface to use. The most simplistic example would be:

```
const user = JSON.parse(userJson) as User;
```

If you want to use a class perhaps for associated methods for data manipulation, you have to instantiate the class using a constructor. This might look like:

```
const userValues = JSON.parse(userJson);
const user = new User(userValues);
```

Comment: Important thing to note: this does not in any way *validate* the JSON. This means that later down the line you may get runtime error saying for example that the `lname` is undefined. The typing only verifies that the TypeScript code is consistent with it self at compile time. Nothing is known about runtime.

As a TypeScript newb I had to have a colleague explain this to me until I understood that there is no *validation* in this pattern.

He also mentioned that people specify their JSON using some other tools which then generate the TypeScript types.

Comment: Here is a question with several answers on what to do if also *runtime* validation is needed: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript

And another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425568/interface-type-check-with-typescript

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
export interface ParcelItemType {    
    itemId: number;
    itemName: string;
}

export interface ParcelType {
    parcelId: number;
    parcelName: string;
    parcelItems: ParcelItemType[];
}

export interface YourType {
   fname: string;
   lname: string;
   parcels: ParcelType[];
}
```