# Is typescript interface validation works after compilation as data validator?

Tags: typescript, validation

I used to use `schema-inspector` for validation. Since I began to use TypeScript, can I get rid of `schema-inspector` validation and create rules to throw and catch errors based on whether data complies with TS's interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an object implements an interface at runtime with TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has no data constructors in the runtime, the only runtime structure which is created by TS is Enum, other things are only type annotations which are used only during compilation, no types exists in the runtime.

That's said, we can say TS types are only information about contract/assumption we make, and they are not verified in the runtime.

If you want to have value constructors, so functions which will create proper value of given type you need or create such by your own, or use some third party library.

Below example of custom made type + value constructor. This kind of tool allows on creating only valid values which match the type assumption:

```
// type
type SomeType = { field: string }
// value constructor
const createSomeType = (a: any): SomeType => {
  const fieldInside = 'field' in a;
  const stringField = typeof a.field === 'string';

  if (!fieldInside || !stringField) {
    throw TypeError('SomeType value was not able to be created');
  }
  return { field: a.field }; // proper value
}

const someValue = createSomeType({ field: 'someStr' }) // correct no error
createSomeType({ otherField: 'x' }) // exception
```