# how to check if a variable is an instanceof FirebaseApp

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have this basic codebase

```
import { FirebaseApp, FirebaseOptions } from "firebase/app";

function example(app){
// error: FirebaseApp only refers to a type
 console.log(app instanceof FirebaseApp)
}
```

here `FirebaseApp` is a typescript interface which is not exists in runtime,
how to check if the provided arg is an instance of firebase app

Answer (score 0):

[`FirebaseApp`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/app/src/public-types.ts#L34) is just an interface and not a class. The `app` is an instance of class [`FirebaseAppImpl`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/app/src/firebaseApp.ts#L30) (implementation of `FirebaseApp`) and cannot be imported from `firebase/app`. If you are just trying to pass the Firebase App instance around, then use `getApp()` function instead:

```
import { getApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseApp = getApp(); // default Firebase app instance
```

Comment: `app === getApp()` does return true if there are the _same_ app instance. But if this is major requirement, Firebase SDKs are open source (linked in answer) and you should be able to expose `FirebaseAppImpl` for your use case.

Comment: I don't want to get the default app, I just want to check that the provided `app` is an instance of firebase app

Comment: @Sheldeeb I would recommend checking out the source code and exposing the `FirebaseAppImpl` class then and perhaps send a raise an feature request issue in Github. Take a look at [Check if object implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33800497/check-if-an-object-implements-an-interface-at-runtime-with-typescript) also.

Comment: FirebaseAppImpl, UserCredentialsImpl and other *Impl classes are not exported by firebase

Comment: @Sheldeeb that's what I mentioned in my answer. You might have to modify the existing source code a bit if you want to use them.