# How to type narrow JSX.Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'd like to have a variable that can be either a React component or a string, like this:

```
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  let icon: JSX.Element | string = "/example.png";  // (simplified)

  return <div>{typeof icon === "JSX.Element" ? icon : <img src={icon} />}</div>;
}
```

however TS complains about my condition saying:

> TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"JSX.Element"' have no overlap.

What should I do?

Comment: Why not ask if typeof is "string" instead?

Comment: @Camilo you're right, that trick would work in this simplified case, but in the full case, I'm using `let icon: JSX.Element | StaticImageData` and Next.js's `Image` component, and it seems not to work there.  Besides, it seems like you should be able to type narrow `JSX.Element` out of the type.

Comment: You may get a better response showing your full custom type example, because it's possible we could modify that type to help you narrow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typeof` operator cannot return `"JSX.Element"`. It can only return the string types listed in that error message:

```
"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

Which means that you will need to check against something in that list, like `"string"`.

```
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  let icon: JSX.Element | string = "/example.png";
  
  return <div>{typeof icon === "string" ? <img src={icon} /> : icon }</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is the best for my simplified question.

If for some reason, you do want to type narrow against the element, rather than against `string`, apparently you can also use [`React.isValidElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement), which type narrows.

You'd have to change the type `JSX.Element` to `ReactElement`:

```
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
  let icon: ReactElement | string = "/example.png";  // (simplified)

  return <div>{React.isValidElement(icon) ? icon : <img src={icon} />}</div>;
}
```

If changing to `JSX.Element` is unacceptable, you could create your own [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which interrogates the object to determine if it is indeed a `JSX.Element` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43279180/2223706)).