# Is there an elegant way to check if the POST request body matches the expected parameters at the endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I implemented a simple server in NodeJS using TypeScript and ExpressJS. At present, in each endpoint, I check if the incoming request body matches the expected parameters in the following way: -

```
express.Router().post('/add', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
     if (!req.body.operand1 || typeof req.body.operand1 !== 'number' ||
         !req.body.operand2 || typeof req.body.operand2 !== 'number') {
          res.send('Request body is invalid');
          return;
     }

     const parameters = req.body;

     res.send(parameters.operand1 + parameters.operand2);
}
```

But this would get tedious if there are many expected parameters in a given endpoint. **What is the best way to achieve this?**

**EDIT**

I edited this question because, before I had included some interfaces and the question looked similar to [Detect whether object implement interface in TypeScript dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013667/detect-whether-object-implement-interface-in-typescript-dynamically), which (understandably) confused people, while the scenario was different from that. There, the asker wanted to know if an object implements an interface. Here, I want to see if the body in a post request is the expected one.

Comment: There are a lot of validation libraries that can do that for you. Otherwise, why not write a simple function that uses the body and a rules object (like your interface) and crosschecks each property in the body with your rules.

Comment: @svenbravo7 Thanks for the reply. I would like to avoid using an external package if possible. I could write a method to cross-check whether a request body matches a particular interface (like the one in my example), but is there a way to make it generic? That is, given any object and interface, can I loop through the properties within the object and see if it matches with the interface. Since I have some experience in C#, reflection is what comes to my mind to do this, but not sure if typescript has anything similar.

Comment: I do not have any experience with Typescript I am afraid. But since that is converted to JS anyway, my gut feeling is telling me that there is no way of doing that out-of-the-box. If you want I can write an example of what I had in mind (without the interfaces)?

Comment: @svenbravo7 Sure!.That may impart some insights to me.

Comment: Done, see my example answer below.

Comment: I recently stumbled upon 'Joi' - https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0 
This was exactly what I was looking for. Don't know how I missed it. Anyway, wanted to share in case anyone would find it helpful [Note: Putting it as comment since this question was closed a while ago]

Answer (score 2):

So here is my example and what I had in mind. Its a very basic example and goes under the assumption that everything you define in your rules MUST be present in the body:

```
const AddEndpointRules = {
    operand1: 'number',
    operand2: 'number'
};

express.Router().post('/add', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    // --- Changed
    if (!matches(req.body, AddEndpointRules)) {
        res.send('Request body is invalid');
        return;
    }
    // ---

    const parameters: AddEndpointParameters = req.body;

    res.send(parameters.operand1 + parameters.operand2);
}

function matches(body, rules) {
    // All keys of rules must be present, so we use that to check our body
    for (let attribute in rules) {
        // The type of value must be same as our rule
        // Not present would mean 'undefined'
        if (typeof body[attribute] !== rules[attribute]) {
            // We invalidate body as soon as we find our first invalid attribute
            return false;
        }
    }

    // All checked out, request body is OK
    return true;
}
```

You can also place the `matches` function in a class of its own and require/import it above your request and use it like for example: Validator.validate() (rename it to validate). That way you can also extend the logic some more and check for length and/or check deeper in the object.

Comment: Thanks. Although not exactly what I wanted since separate JSON (AddEndpointRules) has to be created instead of using the interface (AddEndpointParameters) directly, this would work and can come in handy; and you did mention in the question's comment that you are not experienced with typescript and interfaces. Appreciate the effort. Not marking this as answer, but giving an up-vote since someone might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a schema. It's a way to define what a json object should look like or be formatted as and then use that to compare against the body that is being sent to the API. I would look into this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonschema

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out.