# Is there any way to use TypeScript types to validate JSON objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm working on an API (this is my first time in TypeScript). Traditionally you would type the response you would expect in the `response.body` of your API, something like this:

```
type ApiProps = {
  name: string
  email: string
}
```

Now if I want to know that `response.body` is an `ApiProps` object, from all the posts. I  have found you have to write a type guard manually, doing all the checks. Isn't there a way to avoid writing manually all those type checks? something like:

```
function hasValidProps<T>(body: unknown): body is T {
  // some code using the type definition to validate the type "automatically"
}
```

**Edit: Apparently in 2022 this is still not doable, but I did find a decent workaround below**

```
function hasValidProps<T extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>>(
  body: unknown,
  props: T
): body is T {
  try {
    const bodyObject = JSON.parse(body as string) as Record<string, unknown>
    const bodyObjectKeys = Object.keys(bodyObject)
    const isValid = Object.keys(props).every((key) => bodyObjectKeys.includes(key))
    if (isValid) {
      body = bodyObject
    }
    return isValid
  } catch {
    return false
  }
}

const apiProps = {
  name: '',
  email: ''
}

export type ApiProps = typeof apiProps

// And in your API check...
if (!hasValidProps<ApiProps>(request.body, apiProps)) {
    response.status(400).end()
    return
}
```

Comment: You can use JSON Schema and [Ajv JSON Schema validator](https://ajv.js.org/). You will however need to define JSON Schemas e.g. for your API but that's great documentation and anyone using your API would exactly know what to send to your API.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I don't want to write type guard but rather infer the type's properties at runtime.

Comment: I saw Ajv but it doesn't look like you can actually use the schemas as type - I was looking for something native to TypeScript ideally

Comment: The type system is _gone_ at runtime. So if you can't know the possible types at compile time, _then you can't know the possible types_.

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette - There is no such thing native to TypeScript

Comment: I found this post which is a bit old but it looks like this is still not possible today? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013667/detect-whether-object-implement-interface-in-typescript-dynamically

Comment: Might want to check out [ts-auto-guard](https://github.com/rhys-vdw/ts-auto-guard), or [my abandoned project](https://kelsny.github.io/synth/#generate-type-guards) for some ideas.

Comment: I actually just edited what I find a decent answer... too bad I cannot add it as an answer since the question is closed :)